# Python push fails to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm developing a Reddit bot using PRAW that I'm trying to push to Heroku. When I run `git push heroku master`, I get this error:

```
Counting objects: 40, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 4.13 KiB | 1.38 MiB/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.1
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting altgraph==0.10.2 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/3d/3d8e01dee1379d3250ece6ef9d01292200c1c07086749014a15b7ac01d59/altgraph-0.10.2.tar.gz (481kB)
remote:        Collecting bdist-mpkg==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/98/940f1281edc6091ebbbe1ffac4800cef7dec5bccb64ea2dc3e3a9c6d6974/bdist_mpkg-0.5.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting certifi==2018.10.15 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/9d/1d02dd80bc4cd955f98980f28c5ee2200e1209292d5f9e9cc8d030d18655/certifi-2018.10.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet==3.0.4 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
remote:        Collecting decorator==4.0.11 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/cc/dd79ea98a0ff5a01d714c37eddd99cd0a71557113f1511921d1ef9a083b8/decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting idna==2.7 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
remote:        Collecting macholib==1.5.1 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/12/2a830b5f3e024c50e051f5563eb4fcd61450661d1e41109d6024c8306217/macholib-1.5.1.tar.gz (454kB)
remote:        Collecting modulegraph==0.10.4 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/84/c9a58f832e7722747dc3dfddb1a07d5761930f0b01e39060f61a5e2a112e/modulegraph-0.10.4.tar.gz (532kB)
remote:        Collecting pbr==5.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/04/fddc1c2dd75b256eda4d360024692231a2c19a0c61ad7f4a162407c1ab58/pbr-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (106kB)
remote:        Collecting praw==6.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/d7/0c7fb864ab9469f2964b2787910c78ade6d98c2d1710df1deab61beb99a1/praw-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99kB)
remote:        Collecting prawcore==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/6d/4bf4d65d4771b15c70284c0626d24f230a5de6edac75c446fd22008ddbf6/prawcore-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting py2app==0.7.3 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/37/96be6fba838ef465c48ad701c9243ba9a61b09307c8b463e984fa40d9fee/py2app-0.7.3.tar.gz (1.2MB)
remote:        Collecting pyobjc-core==2.5.1 (from -r /tmp/build_3d8b2e5ccf0b321df85ebefdb32059e1/requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0c/92/51c58aa948bcd4e28b24db694fa94d67b996a041e555c9887a43fe6b794c/pyobjc-core-2.5.1.tar.gz (2.1MB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            You're not running on MacOS X, and don't use GNUstep
remote:            I don't know how to build PyObjC on such a platform.
remote:            Please read the ReadMe.
remote:            
remote:            ObjC runtime not found
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s91svvwa/pyobjc-core/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to calm-fjord-72549.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/calm-fjord-72549.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/calm-fjord-72549.git'
```

I've searched Google repeatedly, and it looks like a lot of people are having this issue, but none of their solutions worked for me. I think it has something to do with Python versions.

Comment: Python 3.7 is still pretty new, wonder if it might be worth downgrading to 3.6.6?

Comment: @SvenHarris I don't think Heroku's stack supports 3.6.6

Comment: I think it should support 3.6.7 (I didn't realise that was a version https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes), will be something you need to specify in your `runtime.txt` file

Comment: Hello. Have you found solution for this? I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on MacOS and trying to have your Heroku Dyno install packages that aren't compatable with it. **Just delete the following three dependencies from your requirements.txt file** and try running `git push heroku master` again and it should resolve the issue:

```
pyobjc-core  
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa 
pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```